# Page refresh File upload and post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given code is inside a Upload button click.My code of upload file is:

```
if (this.fuImage.HasFile) //fuImage is id of FileUploader
{   
string fileName=this.fuImage.FileName;
string strSaveLocation = Path.Combine(physicalpath, fileName);
this.fuImage.SaveAs(strSaveLocation);
}
```

Its work fine.If fuImage has file its save a file on desire location and page is refresh.But if there is not any file and I click a upload button nothing happen no error but page is refresh.I think it is postback issue.Is there any method to prevent to refresh a page if `fuImage` hasn't any file.
`Note:Uploader and button both are server side control.`
Thanks.

Comment: It is not PostBack issue or no problem at all. Based on your code, only file is selected and exists, codes inside if statement will process. Otherwise.. will skip and just post back. Nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't  use  `RequiredFieldValidator` to check whether the file upload control has a file or not?